Объединить 2 строки с одинаковым ID
Имею такую таблицу:



order_id
vzato_v_rabotu
zakrito




abcd
01.10.2024  5:17:15



abcd

01.10.2024  10:05:16



Помогите преобразовать её в такой формат или с помощью excel или же sql:



order_id
vzato_v_rabotu
zakrito




abcd
01.10.2024  5:17:15
01.10.2024  10:05:16



Спасибо заранее!

MAX() + GROUP BY

Спасибо, А можно это сделать в Excel?

@NigarHesenli, в Excel есть такая штука - PowerQuery, это такой построитель мини- SQL запросов, там можно еще и не такие штуки исполнять

А в Excel с этим справится даже сводная таблица.

Уже все решили,@Akina, я опоздал :)
CREATE TABLE orders (
id integer  PRIMARY KEY,
order_id TEXT ,
vzato_v_rabotu  DATETIME,
zakrito DATETIME
);

INSERT INTO orders VALUES (1, 'abcd', '2024-10-01 5:17:15',null);
INSERT INTO orders VALUES (2, 'abcd', null,'2024-10-01 10:05:16');
INSERT INTO orders VALUES (3, 'abcdf', '2024-10-01 9:17:15',null);
INSERT INTO orders VALUES (4, 'abcdf', null,'2024-10-01 12:05:16');


SELECT 
    order_id,
    MIN(vzato_v_rabotu) AS vzato_v_rabotu,
    MAX(zakrito) AS zakrito
FROM 
    orders
GROUP BY 
    order_id;


+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| order_id | vzato_v_rabotu      | zakrito             |
+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| abcd     | 2024-10-01 05:17:15 | 2024-10-01 10:05:16 |
| abcdf    | 2024-10-01 09:17:15 | 2024-10-01 12:05:16 |
+----------+---------------------+---------------------+

https://onecompiler.com/mysql/42y424juc

спасибо! А можно это сделать в Excel?
